# how to set tabs appear in the action bar alongside the action buttons in portrait

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to use the actionbar from the android sdk. When I use the tabs mode, the image in my project is like the picture from the url http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-tabs-stacked@2x.png
We can see the tabs is below the actionbar,If the screen is wide enough as tableTab,it may display as http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-tabs@2x.png

What I want to do!

I just want to let the tabs along the title in actionbar when my deceive's display is in portrait mode.
The SDK says: "ActionBar are ideal because they adapt to different screen sizes". 
For example, when the screen is wide enough the tabs appear in the action bar alongside the action buttons (such as when on a tablet, shown in figure 7), while when on a narrow screen they appear in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action bar", shown in figure 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found a way to work out it,But I don't test it in different screen sizes; I used the customView in actionbar,the view is include a TabHost widget,and set the tabcontent is gone,I set the code to listen the event TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.Here is a demo what I had done.github.com/shellshy/actionbar

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you do not have control over where the tabs go, or even if they will be tabs (instead of being automatically converted into a drop-down list).

Comment: I had found a way to work out it,But I don't test it in different screen sizes; I used the customView in actionbar,the view is include a TabHost widget,and set the tabcontent is gone,I set the code to listen the event TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.Here is a demo what I had done.https://github.com/shellshy/actionbar